# Do Forge Viewer SVF pack files use parent-child linked transforms?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

**Context:** I've been extracting geometry data from the Forge SVF structures  into an *OBJ* format using the [Forge Extract](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-extract) code by Petr. These data are then transparently sent to a different rendering system for the project upon which I'm working. However, I'm noticing that there are incorrect rotations in groups of extracted objects. Not all objects, just groupings.

As an example, here is the Forge Viewer rendering of a group of objects (the long poles), with correct rotation. You can see all the poles evenly placed along the base-plate's edge and equally placed with regards to each other. 
[image: correct rotation]

Whereas in the rendered extracted geometry, the grouping of objects are correctly placed with relation to each other (equally, 3x3), but the group as a whole is rotated slightly along the Z-axis in relation to the bottom plate.

[image: incorrect rotation]

This is the type of behaviour I would expect if the individual poles were all child objects of some parent object (perhaps an invisible grouping object), and the rotation of the parent would pivot all the poles in the SVF but that rotation wasn't applied during geometry extraction. 
This happens with all groupings with regards to individual objects in a scene.

While looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646407/forge-autodesk-models-transform-matrix), I get the strong impression that there is a 2nd rotational aspect but I cannot see how that applies when reading the SVF directly.

---

**Question:**
Obviously I'm not looking for a direct code solution, but to confirm the structure of the SVF pack files. Looking at [the extraction](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-extract/blob/master/src/readers/svf/pack-file-reader.js), I don't see anything which would imply a parent-child grouping but haven't managed to think of an alternative cause.

So, are there such parent-child transform relationships in the SVF pack files, or a global rotational component which only applies to certain objects? If so, where is that placed within the pack file. And if not, what else could cause this type of systematic rotation of groups?

Answer (score 0):

The SVF file format doesn't use parent-child transforms - all fragment transforms are basically world transforms. It's possible that my code for [parsing the fragment transforms](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-extract/blob/master/src/readers/svf/pack-file-reader.js#L98-L120) handles one of the transform types incorrectly. I'd try debugging the `getTransform` method for the dbId of the base or one of the poles, and compare the transform with the one parsed by Forge Viewer.

Also, I'm wondering if it's the base that's slightly off, and not the 3x3 poles?

Comment: Yes, I was considering the same thing with the individual objects. They do, however, seem to be correctly placed, within 0.001 units anyway. 

e.g the base coordinates has  listed XYZs of 
Forge: 4396.771484375, -37926.38671875, -14149
OBJ:   4396.771711947, -37926.385416875, -14149

And I was getting similar line-ups for the posts as well.
So I'm thinking perhaps the central pivot isn't always correct? Or an error in the `getTransform` I'll refactor my code so I can debug that and will post the insights, if any.